# Test Case - Constants for map key

Tags: java, junit4

I have a usecase, where I need to convert from HashMap -> POJO and POJO -> HashMap. I am using Jackson's ObjectMapper to do it.

Now I want to test it, so I need to set all the attributes of POJO as a key in HashMap. I dont want hardcode some thing like this

```
map.put("key","value")
```

neither I want to define big list of constants of the POJO attributes, like

```
static class SomeClass {
    final static String ID = "id";
}
```

as if someone later refactors the class, this will break.

Is there any better way of doing it ?

Comment: Is there any reason why your Pojo can't wrap or extend a hashmap?  Therefore you wouldn't need to translate anything.

Comment: Thanks Razs, yeh pojo can't entend hashmap. its like if you are converting from json to pojo you dont expect pojo to extend json. Hope that helpful.

Comment: Also just in case it is not obvious you know that Jackson's ObjectMapper can transform JSON directly to a POJO and vice versa right?  I'm not sure if that'll remove your mapping steps.

Comment: That was just a example. I am not doing json to pojo its a map to pojo. and ObjectMapper will do that for me too. I want to TEST this conversion process, so I want to write a TestCase, where I generate a map and give it to objectMapper to convert it in to my requested pojo. In my test case, where I am creating Map, I dont want to hard code the keys.